# PHP Script runs fine in browser but not through Command Line

Tags: php, mysql, command-line

I'm Using Xampp on Windows 7. i have the following simple script

```
<?php 
require("classes/autoloader-class.php"); 
$query=new login();
$query->Query("INSERT INTO  poupdate(`po`, `fval`, `nr`, `fsa`, `act`, `doctype`, `usr`) VALUES ('PO','Fval','nr','FSA','ACT','DOCTYPE','USER')");
?>
```

Script Runs fine in Browser and Records are inserted in Database but when i try through following PHP command no records are inserted

```
D:\xampp\php\php.exe -c -f D:\xampp\htdocs\mytest\test.php
```

when i echo something it output text in command line; so i think there is some problem with mysql but no error.

Please Note `-c` is being used to load libraries from php.ini

how i can troubleshoot ? thanks in advance

**[Following Command Helped me in executing Command]**

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\mytest>D:\xampp\php\php.exe -c -f test.php
```

Comment: Does it output any error/warning in console?

Comment: There could be fatal error. Try giving full path in the `require` and try again.

Comment: To see errors you need to turn on the error reporting. Just simply add `ini_set('display_errors', true)` at top of the script and try again.

Comment: Try like this.  "D:\xampp\php\php.exe" -c -f "D:\xampp\htdocs\mytest\test.php"

Comment: @MuthuKumaran it's loading all links and i checked it by changing the require path and showed fatal error

Comment: @SibirajPR i tried it but no success

Comment: Closing means i can't get help on it? then where i can ask for help

Comment: Why negative vote and closing the question ?!!! I had same issue and this thread is giving me info !!! Actually there should be a mechanism to moderate the mindless moderators !!!

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought. Which directory is the working path when you execute via command line? That is: where are you "standing" when you execute the command?

Try moving to the `mytest` folder first.

```
> D:
> cd D:\xampp\htdocs\mytest
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you notice any deviation between `require("classes/autoloader-class.php");` and `D:\xampp\htdocs\mytest\test.php`? Like, you are including files with UNIX-like directory separator, and running script with Windows-like ones.

And that *should* give you an error, check your `php.ini`.

Comment: i have no error displayed

Comment: @Muhammad Haseeb Khan in your php.ini, what value `error_reporting` is set to?

Comment: following is the entry `error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` which means "Show all errors except for notices and coding standards warnings"

Comment: i also edited my question , there seems problem with `mysql connection` because script runs fine and also output if i use echo. But data is not inserted through command line in database